# Selenium WebDriver waitForElementPresent when Javascript refreshes

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I have a Selenium script (Python) using WebDriver that does

```
WebDriverWait(driver, long_wait).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located(find_element(driver, selector))
)
```

However the page the script is "waiting" for the element to appear on is using Javascript to refresh itself. The page refreshes itself every second and a "success" element will appear after a few refreshes. It appears upon refresh the above command exits however I want it to wait indefinitely (or for a long period) even across client/browser refreshing.

Is this possible with WebDriver?

Edit: Here's the body of the method. Ignore my debugging hacks :)

```
def waitForElementPresent(self, driver, selector):
    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10, ignored_exceptions=[
            NoSuchElementException, StaleElementReferenceException
        ]).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(find_element(driver,     selector)))
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print("No such element, waititng again")
        self.waitForElementPresent(driver, selector)

    print("Returning normally")
    return
```

The finally is reached on the first javascript refresh on the client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just wait for the element to be present in a usual way, the recursive approach and special exception handling are not needed here:

```
def waitForElementPresent(driver, selector):
    return WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(selector))

element = waitForElementPresent(driver, (By.ID, "myid"))
```

Comment: NoSuchElementException is ignored by default iirc, however even using the ignored exception code I still get NoSuchElementException when wrapping the call in a try ... puzzling. I suppose I could always loop on that, but that seems a bit grim given the wait API's purpose/design

Comment: @AidenBell correct, `NoSuchElementException` is added by default, just wanted to be explicit. Could you please share the code you are executing now (the relevant part at least; at most, the complete code if this is a public site and I can reproduce the issue too)? Thank you!

Comment: I added the function body being used

Comment: Actually, I think it might be working now ... something odd is going on

Comment: @AidenBell I've updated the answer and added what worked for me on this [sample page](http://www.physiology.wisc.edu/ravi/test/test9.html).

Comment: @AidenBell and yeah, I was wrong, at first, `StaleElementReferenceException` would not make any difference here since there is no element kept before and after the refresh. Though, with the proposed approach, `element` would become "stale" after the next refresh - just in case you would need to use it.

Comment: Yes, this worked. I had issues elsewhere underneath once this was fixed ... but this works and helped me narrow right in on where the underlying issues were. Saved me a good deal of head scratching and code browsing. Thank you!