# Can robot framework keyword can be executed in python console?

Tags: python, selenium, robotframework

I am using robot framework for writing test case. As it is not possible to debug the each and every statement, logging is only way which makes it very slow to develop test case.

I am looking for a way in i can execute the robot keyword in python console. so that I can debug and see if the keyword i have created or inbuilt keyword that i have used will work correctly. 
Is there a way to do it ?

eg. Can i execute `wait until page contains element  ${ELEMENT}`?

Comment: in Selenium IDE there's ``waitForElementPresent`` - seems you can easily replicate it in python. Related SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30327701/4349415

Comment: That was just an example keyword, I am more looking for generic way to do it.  Plus my app is native android app.

Answer (score 0):

Try following plugin on eclipse IDE, it allows you to put a break point and execute step by step.

The last time I checked (couple of months back) it was having few issue with importing existing project and running. I hope they all have been fixed.

https://github.com/nokia/RED

Comment: hi, I don't recall problems with importing existing projects in RED (apart from using pre 0.7.6 run configurations in 0.7.6 which was mentioned in release note).  Everything works fine. (RED PO).

Answer (score -1):

With RED Robot Editor (based on Eclipse) you can run your Robot testcases with debugger. This works the same as other IDE debugger - place breakpoint on executable row (line which consists RF keywords as this is limitation from Robot itself), than you can use step into,step over,variable view&change etc.

If you need to run debugger on Robot and Python level you can use PyDevD (pydev debugger) for python part.

Robot debug: http://nokia.github.io/RED/help/user_guide/launching/debug.html

Robot&Python debug: http://nokia.github.io/RED/help/user_guide/launching/robot_python_debug.html

Comment: duplicate answer to the same answer I have given, if you something more you can put in comment.