# Debugging test cases when they are combination of Robot framework and python selenium

Tags: eclipse, python-3.x, selenium, robotframework

Currently I'm using Eclipse with Nokia/Red plugin which allows me to write robot framework test suites. Support is Python 3.6 and Selenium for it.
My project is called "Automation" and Test suites are in `.robot` files.
Test suites have test cases which are called "Keywords".

**Test Cases**

Create New Vehicle

```
Create new vehicle with next ${registrationno} and ${description}
Navigate to data section
```

Those "Keywords" are imported from python library and look like:

```
@keyword("Create new vehicle with next ${registrationno} and ${description}")
def create_new_vehicle_Simple(self,registrationno, description):
    headerPage = HeaderPage(TestCaseKeywords.driver)
    sideBarPage = headerPage.selectDaten()
    basicVehicleCreation = sideBarPage.createNewVehicle()
    basicVehicleCreation.setKennzeichen(registrationno)
    basicVehicleCreation.setBeschreibung(description)
    TestCaseKeywords.carnumber = basicVehicleCreation.save()
```

The problem is that when I run test cases, in log I only get result of this whole python function, pass or failed. I can't see at which step it failed- is it at first or second step of this function.

Is there any plugin or other solution for this case to be able to see which exact python function pass or fail? (of course, workaround is to use in TC for every function a keyword but that is not what I prefer)

Comment: it's a duplicate of this and other threads. Please search the forum before you put the question. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43974104/can-robot-framework-keyword-can-be-executed-in-python-console

Comment: It's not the same issue. If I have found solution in forum, why would I made trouble to register and write this question? Please read carefully problem and compare with other issue before you mark it as duplicate. Once more, issue which you mentioned and solution there are not helpful for my problem.

Comment: so what are you saying is this solution which you have accepted is not same as provided by two guys in the post you mentioned? please read the guidelines before putting the question

Comment: it is not straight forward that linked questions relates to the same root issue. Same solution does not mean that initial problems are the same.I would even said this question is better worded for future search than other as here you have everything which describes usual problems while debugging Robot - debug works only on Robot level,how to dive into Python stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to "step into" a python defined keyword you need to use python debugger together with RED.

This can be done with any python debugger,if you like to have everything in one application, PyDev can be used with RED.

Follow below help document, if you will face any problems leave a comment here.

[RED Debug with PyDev](http://nokia.github.io/RED/help/user_guide/launching/robot_python_debug.html)

Comment: I have installed Red by using eclipse marketplace. First regarding environment setup: I didn't have option Python Nature when right clicking on project. 
All other step described under that link I did and at end I debugged run test suite by using new created robot debug configuration but still get same log/report, only detailed to robot keyword but black box to python functions.
Should I run debug on the python library level?

Comment: Python/PyDev nature is only available after you install PyDev into Eclipse. Install it to RED/Eclipse and off you go. If you would use pydevd (pydev debuger) directly from Eclipse folder,you need to update path in script: https://github.com/nokia/RED/blob/master/src/RobotUserScripts/runPyDevDebug.py  on line 91

Comment: You still need to place debug breakpoint inside py files, python debugger will provide stack traces of what is happening.

Comment: just to inform you that somehow it works now. All I did was to delete older debug configuration and create new one ...

Answer (score 2):

If you are wanting to know which statement in the python-based keyword failed, you simply need to have it throw an appropriate error. Robot won't do this for you, however. From a reporting standpoint, a python based keyword is a black box. You will have to explicitly add logging messages, and return useful errors.

For example, the call to `sideBarPage.createNewVehicle()` should throw an exception such as "unable to create new vehicle". Likewise, the call to `basicVehicleCreation.setKennzeichen(registrationno)` should raise an error like "failed to register the vehicle".

If you don't have control over those methods, you can do the error handling from within your keyword:

```
@keyword("Create new vehicle with next ${registrationno} and ${description}")
def create_new_vehicle_Simple(self,registrationno, description):
    headerPage = HeaderPage(TestCaseKeywords.driver)
    sideBarPage = headerPage.selectDaten()
    try:
        basicVehicleCreation = sideBarPage.createNewVehicle()
    except:
        raise Exception("unable to create new vehicle")

    try:
        basicVehicleCreation.setKennzeichen(registrationno)
    except:
        raise exception("unable to register new vehicle")

    ...
```

Comment: even in this case, when I run my test case I will get general error message for whole keyword  ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visible

Comment: Its robot based test suites, tests and keywords and run with python -m robot

Comment: @domoni: it is up to you to make sure you emit good error messages. There's nothing in robot framework or in python that is preventing you from emitting useful error messages.

Comment: in this case I am limited and yes robot framework prevent me currently to get correct debug and correct pointing to problem

Comment: @domoni: how so? In the example I showed you how your `create_new_vehicle_Simple` keyword can return error messages specifically addressing the actual failure.

Comment: Because for Robotframework whole python part is taken as blackbox and I will get one error message with notification what went wrong but not where it was wrong, even when I put exceptions as you suggested. Robot will just write "Create new vehicle with next ${registrationno} and ${description}" FAIL: Elemento not visible or something like that

Comment: If your keyword throws an error like in my example, it is impossible for it to throw "Element not visible".  If you're getting "element not visible" then that means you aren't catching the error and then throwing something more useful. There's nothing at all preventing your code from catching "element not visible" and throwing any other error that you want. You simply need to be diligent, and put try/except around every block of code that should return a custom error message.

Comment: But also I have many lines where are performed lot of actions on elements under function Eg. sideBarPage.createNewVehicle(), so I will got message that this function didnt work but I will not be able to see at which point.

Comment: And just one thing, I put one test case as you described, put Try / except all over, still got only this at test log "Starting test: DatacenterUiTests.TestAutomationSuites.FunctionalTestScripts.General - Anzeige Hilfeseite
20170612 14:15:31.432 : FAIL : StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

I don't know if you have experience with Robot framework with Python or your suggestions are based only on python keywords experience.

Comment: @domoni: I probably have more robot experience than all but one user on all of stackoverflow. I've written many thousands of lines of python code to be used as keywords stretching back several years, and I have more reputation on the robotframework tag than the next 15 people combined.

Comment: Ok, thx for explaining. Well I don't know then why I get only Robot pointing to the error cause and not python also.

Comment: @domoni: the "why" is because you aren't catching the error. You have a block of code that calls one or more selenium functions, and that block of code isn't catching the error.  If you want to create keywords and functions that give useful error messages, it is your responsibility to catch the errors and reformat them to something that will be useful to you.

Comment: in previous comment I wrote that I added "try / except" into my python script code as you suggested and still get log error which I posted you in previous comments and always got only message what went wrong in keyword, element not found, element not visible, document error, type error... but not where it happened at which line and also I didn't get messages which I defined under exceptions which I wrote (once more in the way you suggested). Please read history.